# Rapid Firecannon Interaction with Rengar's Passive

Tags: league-of-legends

> Rapid Firecannon 
> Stats
>   +30% attack speed
>   +8% movement speed
>   +30% critical strike chance
>  UNIQUE – ENERGIZED STRIKE: Moving and attacking generates Energize stacks, up to 100. When fully Energized,
>   your next basic attack gains FIRECANNON and deals 50 - 200 (based on
>   level) bonus on-hit magic damage.
>  UNIQUE – FIRECANNON: Your next basic
>   attack gains 35% increased range, up to a maximum of +150 range.
>   FIRECANNON can be used on structures.

As your next basic attack is granted extra range, does it also increase your leap range for Rengar's passive? If not then why is it a rather popular choice of item for a lot of Rengar builds?

Comment: I still prefer Dead man's plate. The bonus movement speed you get makes up for the increased range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regnars passive:

> UNSEEN PREDATOR: While in brush or in stealth, Rengar gains bonus
>   attack range and his basic attacks cause him to dash to his target.
>   This bonus lasts for 0.5 seconds upon exiting brush or stealth. Unseen
>   Predator occurs regardless of whether or not his target has Sight icon
>   sight of him.

As you can see, his next attack gains bonus attack range - and with the *Rapid Firecannon* he gains even more attack range

so the answer is - yes it does